# SyntaxError: Unexpected token in node.js

Tags: jquery, node.js

Am using following code to fetch data from server .but in place of

```
var  jobData = JSON.parse(data);
```

Am getting

```
undefined:1
1afcec877d925d110","date":"Mon Jan 06 2014 09:33:13 GMT+0530 (IST)","id":"51",
                                                                              ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
    at Object.parse (native)
```

code

```
var options = {
                    host: '172.16.2.120',
                    path: '/getModes?mode=' + jobLists,
                    port: '8080',
                    method: 'GET'
                };

                var reqOs = http.request(options, function (resOs) {
                    resOs.on('data', function (data) {              
                   var jobData = JSON.parse(data);              
                    });
                    resOs.on('end', function () {           

                    });
                });
                reqOs.on('error', function (e) {
                    console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
                });
                reqOs.end('');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to accumulate the chunks of data passed to the `data` event handler, and process them  when the HTTP request has ended:

```
var reqOs = http.request(options, function (resOs) {
  var chunks = [];
  resOs.on('data', function (chunk) {
    chunks.push(chunk);
  });
  resOs.on('end', function () {
    var json    = Buffer.concat(chunks);
    var jobData = JSON.parse(json);
    ...
  });
});
```

The reason for this is that the `data` event can be triggered in the middle of reading a response.

Comment: you should replace `chunks.push(chunk);` by `chunks.push(new Buffer(chunk));` and `Buffer.concat(chunks);` by `Buffer.concat(chunks).toString();` ;)

Comment: 'cause json parsing the result of `Buffer.concat` throw an error in last node js versions.

Comment: @GuillaumeCisco not for me ([gist](https://gist.github.com/robertklep/6e4154763f9d8f7d9f3f), tried with Node v0.12). Are you sure the data is valid JSON to begin with?

Comment: Absolutely, node version 0.13-pre. But I think it is exactly the same thing with node v0.12. I'll try to show you an example ;)

Comment: Here is an example:
`> Buffer.concat(['{"toto":', '"tutu}"'])
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Function.Buffer.concat (buffer.js:209:9)`

But this is correct:
`Buffer.concat([new Buffer('{"toto":'), new Buffer('"tutu}"')])`

Comment: @GuillaumeCisco in Node 0.12 (and lower), the chunks provided by the `data` event are also `Buffer`'s, so there's no problem in concatenating those. We'll have to wait for Node 0.14 to get released to see if the problem you're describing will persist.

Comment: Oh yes! You're right! I use `resOs.setEncoding('utf8');` before making my `data` callback. Maybe it was a part of my issues. Hope it'll help others ;)

Comment: @GuillaumeCisco ah yes when you set encoding, you'll get strings instead of Buffers

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the JSON string your server is responding is not valid:

```
1afcec877d925d110","date":"Mon Jan 06 2014 09:33:13 GMT+0530 (IST)","id":"51",
                                                                             ^
```

If the string ends like that, it's not valid JSON. Check the JSON string your server is returning and try to make it valid.

Comment: That doesn't mean it can't return an invalid JSON string.